# Repeat block of regex in regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure out a nice line of regex to match the following:

```
1:[any chars here except newlines]|1:[any chars here except newlines]...
```

I want my regex to be able to match an infinite number of repeats of this type. The clostest I've come to figuring it out is with `'(1:[^|]*\|)\1+'`, but it doesn't work for two reasons. Firstly, that will only find strings that have an additional pipe at the end of the string. Secondly, the text within the first capture must be the same throughout.

I could solve this using a split, but I just wondered if there was a nice way of doing this in a regular expression.

Comment: Do you care if the regex matches `1:foo|` as well?

Comment: Yes I do, and it can't match any instances like `|0:bar`. They must all be `1:something`.

Comment: You've tagged `python` and `pcre` regular expressions, which are not the same. Do you care which language it's in?

Comment: If you can solve it with a split, then you probably should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the quantifier to the entire group:

```
^(?:1:[^|\n]*\|?)+(?<!\|)$
```

`^` asserts the position at the beginning of the string. It then matches `1:` followed by any characters that are not `|` or a newline, *zero* or more times (indicated by the `*`). This entire group can be repeated *one* or more times (indicated by the `+`). The `(?<!\|)` is a negative lookbehind that asserts that the last character is not a `|`. `$` asserts position at the end of the string.

It matches all of these:

```
1:foo
1:foo|1:bar
1:foo|1:bar|1:baz
1:foo|1:bar|1:baz|1:bak
```

But will not match

```
1:foo|
```

and similar.

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bH1xW5/6)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works for matching those, but it also matches instances like these `1:foo|1:bar|0:foo`. I'm trying to make it as specific as possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this,

```
^(1:[^|\n]*)(?:\|(?1))*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bA9hW7/1)

`(?1)` Recurses the first capturing group. Read more about recursive regex at [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) .

For languages which won't support recursive regex.

```
^(?:1:[^|\n]*)(?:\|1:[^|\n]*)*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bA9hW7/3)

Python code:

```
In [10]: import re

In [11]: s = """1:[any chars here except newlines]|1:[any chars here except newlines]
...: 1:[any chars here except newlines]
...: 1:foo
...: 1:foo|1:bar
...: 1:foo|1:bar|1:baz
...: 1:foo|1:bar|1:baz|1:bak
...: 1:foo|"""
In [14]: for i in re.findall(r'(?m)^(?:1:[^|\n]*)(?:\|1:[^|\n]*)*$', s):
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     
1:[any chars here except newlines]|1:[any chars here except newlines]
1:[any chars here except newlines]
1:foo
1:foo|1:bar
1:foo|1:bar|1:baz
1:foo|1:bar|1:baz|1:bak
```